# CID integration with DXA

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa2.2

I am using ContextualMediaHelper with DXA 2.2 solution. To avoid cropping of images, I want to use fit instead of scale with CID service. I can see scale is appended in the responsive image URL configuration hardcoded within ContextuaMediaHelper.cs class file.

[image]

Wondering if there is any other way except creating custom Media helper to use fit in the responsive URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already found yourself that use of “scale” is hard-coded in `ContextualMediaHelper`. But you can also see that it is a property, which is set with a hard-coded value in the constructor.

So, a custom MediaHelper can be very minimal: create a subclass of `ContextualMediaHelper` which only has a constructor which sets the `ImageResizeUrlFormat` to the desired value.